BottomSheetScaffold usage
I am new to this. But, I want a BottomSheetScaffold to display another view found in my file MailView.kt when I click on a button. I want the sheet hidden till the button is clicked.
But, (BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Hidden) and sheetState in my code give an error I am not sure how to solve.

Cannot find a parameter with this name: sheetState
This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.
Unresolved reference: Hidden
No value passed for parameter 'onClose'

This is the full code:
      var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    if (showBottomSheet) {
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            sheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Hidden),
            sheetContent = {
                MailView(onClose = { showBottomSheet = false })
            },
            content = {
                MailView()
            }
        )
    }

And this is how my button is set to work:
Button(
                                    onClick = { scope.launch { sheetState.show() } },
                                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                                        containerColor = Color(
                                            0xffae52de
                                        )
                                    ),

UPDATE:
Based on recommended answer, I tried this for the BottomSheetScaffold:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(skipHiddenState = false))

  BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
             MailView {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide()
                }
            })
        },
        content = {
            // Your main content
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp // Ensure the sheet is hidden initially
    )


And this for the button:
Button(
    onClick = {
scope.launch {
scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
 }
}


But, it does not seem to trigger the sheet.

UPDATE:
I wanted to know how I can shift the content of the BottomSheetScaffold up a bit further to the top. The content seems to be positioned a little too low in the sheet for me.


You import the wrong version of rememberModalBottomSheetState. The material3 version takes a Boolean and returns a SheetState, but you need the androidx.compose.material.rememberModalBottomSheetState one.
Edit:
Here is an example with a button that shows bottom sheet on click.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Example() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
            initialValue = PartiallyExpanded,
        ),
    )

    val hideBottomSheet: () -> Unit = {
        scope.launch { scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand() }
    }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = { MailView(hideBottomSheet) },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp // Ensure the sheet is hidden instead of being partially expanded
    ) {
        Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Show MailView")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MailView(onHide: () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onHide) { Text("Hide") }
}


Thanks so much. As the app uses material 3, I found and decided to use BottomSheetScaffold. But, I am getting these errors now.
UPDATED

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work, I've added a working example based on it. @MaryKay

I tried it and it worked in the new project! I just wonder if my NavigationBar is not covering it as it is small. Is there a way to make it appear to almost fill the entire screen?

UPDATE: It seems to be solved by sending the code below all the other content. Please, I have a bar, with a close button and a logo and text to sort of be a top nav bar in the sheet...
Is there a way to implement that in a way to have it at the very top? I do not know if you get what I mean. I will update with a picture, please.
Cause it looks a little weird. :)

I don't quite get what you mean. Also, please avoid reediting your post with the new questions, it creates an unreadable mess and lowers the chance of getting an answer. If you have a new question, please create a new post with a detailed explanation. @MaryKay

Oh okay please. So sorry about that. I did not know that.
I just want to shift the content of the BottomSheetScaffold up a bit further to the top.
The content of the sheet seem to be positioned a little too low in the bottomscaffoldSheet for me (like in the picture)
I need assistance on how to push the content up further.

there is no parameter called sheetState in BottomSheetScaffold instead use scaffoldState and pass scaffoldState variable to it.
also add @OptIn( ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class) on top of your @Composable(
so the warning will be removed).
and for No value passed for parameter 'onClose' it has nothing to do with BottomSheetScaffold it means that MailView() composable fun does not have
lambda parameter named onClose
code implementation:
  val bottomSheetScaffoldState =
    rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

  
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetState = scaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            // sheet content
        },
        content = {
           //scaffold content
        }
    )


How do I add a hidden feature to the bottomSheetScaffold. And have it appear with a button onClick? And what kind of elements are meant to be put in the scaffold content? I want to display another view MailView in the sheet itself.
